# TarantoolClient select example usage

Tags: java, tarantool

I want to test performance of several NoSQL solutions (MongoDB, Tarantool and Kyoto). Our backend developed on Java using SpringFramework, so in Tarantool case I try to use java-client specified in [documentation](https://www.tarantool.org/doc/book/connectors/index.html#java).
I configured TarantoolClient in my application according to the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java).
But library version 1.7 is snapshot only, so I don't have any javadoc.
Has anybody some examples of usage this library? How can I convert Tarantool answer to my java object?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use version 1.6.7 and also could look at usage examples on github under the 1.6.7 tag.

Comment: You could also look for client 1.7 usage example in the integration test folder.